# How to dynamically specify binding from a UserControl's attribute to one of my objects, when there is an intermediary UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding

I want to create a user control in which users can specify settings for the application. I've created a `CheckBoxPreference` control that represents a setting. I want each setting to map to a property in `MySettings` (which in turn maps to `IsolatedStorage`).

Ideally, I could specify a Key attribute in `CheckBoxPreference` which would map to the property value of the same name. So for example below I've specified `Key="PlayAppAudio"` and a property called `PlayAppAudio` in `MySettings`

**How can I get the `PlayAppAudio` attribute to map to `MySettings.PlayAppAudio`?**

The code I have so far is as follows:

MainPage.xaml contains:

```
        <StackPanel>
            <my:CheckBoxPreference 
                Title="Play Application Audio" 
                Summary="Play application audio events"
                DefaultValue="True" 
                Key="PlayAppAudio" />

            <my:CheckBoxPreference 
                Title="Allow Vibrations" 
                Summary="Allow device to vibrate"
                DefaultValue="True" 
                Key="AllowVibrations" />
        </StackPanel>
```

The Key attribute is the property I want to map.

`CheckBoxPreference` is defined as:

```
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" >

            <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=MyUserControl}" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Name="txtDescription" Text="{Binding Path=Summary, ElementName=MyUserControl}" FontSize="20"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--<CheckBox 
            IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource MySettings}, 
            Path=PlayAppAudio, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            Grid.Column="1"/>-->

        <CheckBox Name="Bindable"             
            Grid.Column="1"/>
```

with the following code-behind:

```
public partial class CheckBoxPreference : UserControl
{

    public CheckBoxPreference()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(String), typeof(CheckBoxPreference), null);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SummaryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Summary", typeof(String), typeof(CheckBoxPreference), null);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof(String), typeof(CheckBoxPreference), null);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckBoxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultValue", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBoxPreference), null);

    public String Title
    {
        get { return GetValue(TitleProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public String Summary
    {
        get { return GetValue(SummaryProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(SummaryProperty, value); }
    }

    public String Key
    {
        get { return GetValue(KeyProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool DefaultValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CheckBoxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckBoxProperty, value); }

    }
}
```

And MySettings has the properties that I want to map to, defined as

```
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool PlayAppAudio
    {
        get { return _playAppAudio; }
        set
        {
            bool old = _playAppAudio;
            _playAppAudio = value;
            if (value != old)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PlayAppAudio");
            }
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool AllowVibrations
    {
        get { return _allowVibrations; }
        set
        {
            bool old = _allowVibrations;
            _allowVibrations = value;
            if (value != old)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AllowVibrations");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind `CheckBoxPreference`'s check box to the new property `self->IsChecked`, and add listening method that will listen for `Key` property change and change `IsChecked` accordingly...

Here is link on how you can listen for PropertyChanged events:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx